# Notation of sum $a+b+c+\cdots=n$ without repeatings

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation, factorial

I sure my question is simple. We have, for example
$$\sum\limits_{a+b+c+\cdots=n}\frac{(a+b+c+\cdots)!}{a!b!c!\cdots}$$
then for $n=6$ exists 5 pairs: (5,1), (4,2), (3,3), (2,4), (1,5)

or 10 triples: (4,1,1), (3,2,1), (3,1,2), (2,3,1), (2,2,2), (2,1,3), (1,4,1), (1,3,2), (1,2,3), (1,1,4) and so on.

Is there a specific notation, where we use for sum only 3 pairs (5,1), (4,2), (3,3) or only 3 triples (4,1,1), (3,2,1), (2,2,2)?

Is also there a special symbol or something, which denote, that if some elements of sum are equal, ex. $a=d=h=2$, $b=e=k=r=3$, we need to divide that term by $q_{1}!q_{2}!\cdots$ (where $q_{k}$ - quantity of elements (a,d,h) or (b,e,k,r) and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, when you go from order mattering to order not mattering, you are going from "[compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))" to "[partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))".

For your second question, if this is supposed to be used with partitions, then there's just a scaling involved. There are $18!$ permutations of distinct $(a,b,\ldots,r)$, and there are $18!/(3!4!)$ permutations where $a=d=h$ and $b=e=k=r$ and no other things are equal. Therefore, if you just do the sum over the compositions and divide by $18!$, you'll get the appropriately adjusted sum over the partitions.

Comment: Thank you for answer! If you want understand, which about concretely I asked, look here (http://www.convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/Reference/AMS55.ASP?Res=150&Page=831&Submit=Go). Notation, of course, a little bit ugly.